# How to auto-increment in python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I want to print all available functions in os module as:

```
1 functionName

2 functionName

3 functionName
```

and so on.

Currently I am trying to get this kind of output with following code:

```
import os

cur = dir(os)
for i in cur:
    count = 1
    count += 1
    print(count,i)
```

But it prints as below:

```
2 functionName

2 functionName

2 functionName
```

till end.

Please help me generate auto increment list of numbers, Thanks.

Comment: There is a nice preview tool that allows you to format your code correctly

Comment: you're setting `count` to `1` on every iteration...

Comment: Put `count = 1` outside of your loop and run your code again

Comment: Placing ``count = 1`` outside does not work. Could you please give me a example code?

Comment: @techydesigner - That's what OP is doing with `dir()`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Its because you've re-defined the `count` variable or reset it to 1 for each loop again. I'm not into python but your code doesn't make sense since everytime the count variable is first set to 1 and then incremented. I'd simply suggest the following.

```
import os

cur = dir(os)
count = 1
for i in cur:
    count += 1
    print(count,i)
```

Answer (score 6):

The pythonic way to do this is [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). If we pass the keyword argument `start=1`, the count will begin at 1 instead of the default 0.

```
import os

cur = dir(os)
for i, f in enumerate(cur, start=1):
    print("%d: %s" % (i, f))
```

Comment: Wow,  its great! Thanks. :)